# Como sumar minutos a int php

Tags: php, datetime

Tengo el siguiente contador de días para saber cuanto se demora en responder una solicitud.

Aparte realizo un calculo para saber cuantas hora se demora en responder.

```
$counter = 0;
$fecha1 = '2019-06-20'; 
$fecha2 = '2019-06-24'; 

  for($i=$fecha1; $i<$fecha2; $i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))) {
    if (date("w",strtotime($i)) != 5 && date("w",strtotime($i)) != 6) { $counter++;}
   }
        $counter = $counter * 9;
        $time1 = new DateTime('12:00');
        $time2 = new DateTime('12:30');
        $interval = $time1->diff($time2);
```

En el siguiente ejemplo tengo una solicitud que demoro 2 dias en responder lo multiplico x la cantidad de horas por dia que son `9`, despues realizo una resta del tiempo `00:30`.

Como yo puedo sumar y obtener resultado `18:30`, ya que este es el total de tiempo que demoro en responder.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un modo sencillo es conseguir el total de minutos y operar para darle el formato de horas (minutos / 60) y minutos restantes (resto de la división anterior). Siguiendo tu ejemplo:

```
    $counter = 2;
    $time1 = new DateTime('12:00');
    $time2 = new DateTime('12:30');
    $time = $counter*9*60 + $interval->i;
    echo intVal($time/60).":".($time%60);
    //18:30
```